# Chrome Version 66.0.3359.139 lost my sessions on reboot

Tags: google-chrome, memory, chromium

I seldom shut down my computer, but yesterday I shut down my computer to add new ram, and I got logged out of all my websites. Why is that I got lost all my sessions and was logged out of all the websites?

Comment: No, the OS should conceal such details from application programs.

Comment: @sawdust: Individual RAM chips, yes. But the total amount of RAM available? Programs certainly can ask the OS about that. Some even use it for DRM.

Comment: @grawity -- I defer to RedGrittyBrick's answer as a response to your questions, and Evan Carroll's answer for the likely cause.  Note that the OP has revised the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Chrome does not do any such thing, it seems there is a known bug that causes this that's already been reported.

- https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=800414
- https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=827522 (less technical "flake" that points to this one)

Answer (score 1):

> **Does Google Chrome nuke the sessions when it detects ram changes?**

No.

> **Does Chrome keep a catalog of the hardware it's running on for this purpose?**

No.

---

A website session is a server-side concept where the state of a session (e.g. logged in or not) is kept by the server. Typically the server issues a cookie to the client which links subsequent HTTP connections with the established session.

The browser will respect the cookie's expiry date & time as set by the server.

The server can independently change the state of a session or deem it closed. For example a banking website server would manage session-timeout server-side because a malicious custom client might attempt to misuse an expired cookie.

An unexpected logout across several websites which allow multi-day "sessions" is probably because the cookies expired, were deleted, mislaid or set-aside (e.g. running browser in privacy mode)

---

An application such as a web-browser typically only cares about whether it has enough memory allocated to it. If it needs more memory, it asks the OS to supply it. It doesn't care if this is real RAM or virtual memory backed by SSD, disk or other storage media. It doesn't care about the total amount of physical memory available to the operating system or as-yet unallocated to other applications. The whole point of demand-paged virtual memory systems is to isolate applications from concerns such as total RAM installed.